# Windows 10 bat Script get stuck on large files

Tags: batch-file, pause

I got a bat script that is starting in one part sort to sort large text files ~ 3-40 Gigabye. The part is

```
@Echo     Merge ..
D:/filetype/core/sort.exe -b -T D:\filetype\core\tmp\ D:\filetype\module\model_bruteforce\merge\merged_tmp1.txt -o D:\filetype\module\model_bruteforce\merge\merged_tmp2.txt
del "D:\filetype\module\model_bruteforce\merge\merged_tmp1.txt" > nul 2>&1
@Echo     Fixing forwardslash ..
```

sort.exe is closed properly after the job is done but the bat script getting stuck and pauses before `@Echo Fixing forwardslash` (without message), i often need to press the enter key to go on to the next step, but not everytime.

What can cause this? And how could i get more stability? I first saw this after i went from a Windows 10 64 bit to a new more powerful computer but also with windows 10 64 bit, both computer got only a HDD Hardisk but using different CP and GPU's

Comment: [`sort`](http://ss64.com/nt/sort.html) uses a temporary file, so you need to ensure that there is enough free space on your HDD (I guess you need at least as much memory as the size of the file to sort is)...

Comment: `> nul 2>&1` suppresses messages. It could be that `del` is waiting for a keyboard response - I'd suggest removing that redirection and observing. For an automatic brute-force response (you say you need to press enter...) try `echo.|del` - no guarantees.